# jQuery date picker in Windows 8 App

Tags: jquery, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am using the following date picker code in my Windows 8 App:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input id="date" type="textbox"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#date").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/icon_cal.png' });
    });
</script>
```

This code works pretty much fine in we browser but when i use the same code inside VS code for Win8 app, it crashes and gives error:

```
Unhandled exception at line 74, column 26 in ms-appx://28644916-f22c-432f-a4f7-1b6441506d79/default.html

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'
```

Line74:

$("#date").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/icon_cal.png' });

Comment: This means jQuery UI is not loaded.

Comment: oh o.. but what can be the solution for this

Comment: Checking the path to jQuery UI and Loading it correctly.

Comment: Why r u including 3 different jQuery files ?? jus include the latest version and try again

Comment: path is correct. jquery.jquerymin are in project/js/ folder.

Comment: @sushanthreddy i removed those. Now i am including just jquery and jquerymin files

Comment: @V.J. You only need one. The min version is the minified version of the other.

Comment: @LeeTaylor yes i understand that. did that but no luck yet

Comment: @VJ you need to include the jqueryui files as well. You can find it here http://jqueryui.com/download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea was to use a simple jQuery UI library which i did not used. Thanks to @Hallie for pointing it out. I did not knew about this thing.